# How to get shortcut to a button with ALT?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts

We know, as we press <kbd>Alt</kbd> on keyboard, and press combination <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>*letter*</kbd> we get to it fast. For example <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>e</kbd> (current page), and so on.

But how we can get to  <kbd>OK</kbd> or <kbd>Cancel</kbd> button in this case?

[image]

Comment: [This](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/126449) should help in the future.

Answer (score 2):

In this case, you can press <kbd>Enter</kbd> or <kbd>spacebar</kbd> to hit the <kbd>OK</kbd> button, since it's the currently active button (You can see it has a dark border around the button).

For the <kbd>Cancel</kbd> button, the surefire way would be to press <kbd>Tab</kbd> (untill the Cancel button is active) followed by <kbd>spacebar</kbd>. This works because <kbd>Tab</kbd> cycles through the input fields (text fields, drop down lists, buttons etc.) in the window which currently has focus, also known as the active window, and <kbd>spacebar</kbd> activates the active button as described above.

In most cases you can also press <kbd>Esc</kbd> to close the window (similar to activating the cancel button), since standard behavior in Windows is that <kbd>Enter</kbd> is "OK" and <kbd>Esc</kbd> is "Cancel", which holds true for most dialogue boxes.

---

From Microsoft support website ([source](http://support2.microsoft.com/kb/126449)) - credit to [rrirower](https://superuser.com/users/279489/rrirower):

**Dialog box keyboard commands**

- <kbd>Tab</kbd>: Move to the next control in the dialog box
- <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd>: Move to the previous control in the dialog box
- <kbd>Spacebar</kbd>: If the current control is a button, this clicks the button. If the current control is a check box, this toggles the check box. If the current control is an option, this selects the option.
- <kbd>Enter</kbd>: Equivalent to clicking the selected button (the button with the outline)
- <kbd>Esc</kbd>: Equivalent to clicking the Cancel button
- <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>*underlined letter*</kbd> in dialog box item: Move to the corresponding item

Comment: _For the Cancel button, the surefire way would be to press Tab followed by spacebar._  While your answer is correct, you should clarify that Tab must be clicked until the focus is current on the Cancel button.  Without knowing the tab order, you can't assume the number of clicks required to focus the Cancel button.

Comment: A simplification on my part, as in 99.9% of the applied scenarios, the Cancel button would be next in line after the OK button. But you are quite right. It assumes that the Cancel button is the next button in the tab order. But as there is no way to determine this except by trying it, it's hard to include in a short answer without complicating matters.